# Status Bar orientation problems

Tags: ipad, ios, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm having this issue with the application status bar on My iPad app.

I'm using a UINavigationController. The root view controller allows all rotations by returning YES in the shoulAutoRotate method. This root view controller has two distict looks when it comes to portrait or landscape orientation, which I have managed to modify programmatically without using a nib file.

The thing is that when I start my App in landscape, sometimes the status bar will be in portrait. This will either cause a white bar on top of the view, or to force the VC to load the portrait view when the iPad is in landscape mode.

I verified my plist file and it's correctly set up for the orientations needed

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

The other thing that happens is that when I push a view controller in landscape mode, that does not show the status bar, it will disappear correctly. But then when that vc is popped by the navigation controller, the status bar will return in portrait or even portrait upside down.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? 
I could put lots of code but I don't want to make the question unreadable. Feel free to ask whatever part of the code you need.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES; }
```